# Windows PhoneToolkit ListPicker: implementing a countries list as in the settings?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-toolkit

I have a list of countries that I want to display in a list similar to that in the phone settings app

[image]

[image]

I tried using the toolkit's ListPicker but it had a poor performance in loading as the list size is large, it seems that this is a known issue with ListPicker.

is there any alternatives to implementing such a list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but here's the solution that worked for me:

- Implement a new page with a ListBox.
- In the new page, when an item is selected, save the selected Item/Index in the `PhoneApplicationService.Current.State`
- Then navigate backwards and retrieve the saved Item/Index from the page state.